# Data showing in Grid but not in export file Magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, csv, custom-reports

I have created a custom report,

Used below code in my ui_component listing file.

```
<column name="custom_tax_code" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
  <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Code</item>
 </item>
</argument>
</column>

<column name="shipping_amount_custom" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Amount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Then in **Quantity.php**

```
 class Quantity extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

  public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {       
     foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

     $item['custom_tax_code'] = $taxcode; // used some logic to get this value
     $item['shipping_amount_custom'] = $lastItemShippingAmt;// used some logic to get this value
     }
  }
   return $dataSource;
  }
}
```

This code is working fine and it is showing properly in admin Grid, But when exported to CSV, values for these 2 columns are not showing. likewise i have many other custom columns. posted only 2 here.

How to resolve this issue? Can anyone help me out please. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento doesn't render the custom fields on export.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14014

You should add some specific customization for export. 
I suppose in case dynamic values you can add plugins for these methods:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/06dbbc86572e110ecb60c52e8f54a8a144262d56/app/code/Magento/Ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php#L64-L103

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/06dbbc86572e110ecb60c52e8f54a8a144262d56/app/code/Magento/Ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php#L154-L170

P.S. Otherwise you can try to add your needed data to collection directly, using custom attributes or join to needed table(s), so that the code `$document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue()` retrieve the correct value.

Here we can see how was solved the similar issue with empty fields in the exported CSV for customer grid -

[\Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document::getCustomAttribute()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12373/commits/5f3ef1bc5065edba95b041b11887a961fd3c8cdd#diff-fc91e803f0db2cc4846e68eb4692f2deR110-R115)

Comment: hi @Sergi.sss, I'm not cleared, where is the working code here?

Comment: @jafar pinjar If you want a working solution, you need to provide your extension code entirely.

Comment: hi @sergei, can you pls share your email id?

Comment: You can temporary upload your code to github, it will be more convenient for me to change it. And more people will be able to help you.

Comment: you can check the module here, https://github.com/pinjar/CustomReport

Comment: could you get time to check this @sergei

Comment: @jafarpinjar see my pull request - https://github.com/pinjar/CustomReport/pull/1    I have added your custom_zip_code to export.

Comment: is it working? @sergei? Also I have many other columns like 'custom_tax_code', have u checked my module?

Comment: hi @sergei, yes i did pull request, its worked for me, I'll add code for remaining custom coulmns, but this has one issue, once we click on sort on date its not working, could you please check and update me.

Comment: @jafarpinjar Error on sorting isn't related to your current question about export and my customization. Maybe the better way to resolve it - ask another question.

Comment: sure, Thanks a lot @sergei.ss

Answer (score 0):

I crate a Admin Grid using Ui-Component.

You  want all Data you have create a Custom Export  Button that export your all data.

edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add Button into Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">

    <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>

    <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>

</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you define in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and See your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: hi @Msquare, I haven't tried this code, the code i used is almost similar, can you pls help me with that, https://github.com/pinjar/CustomReport

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes i will helps you.